# Command line options to jump to search term in .txt file searched from within Xbench (and opened in EmEditor)

Tags: emeditor

I am using a glossary search program called [Xbench](https://www.xbench.net/), and it allows you to use command line parameters to automatically jump to the relevant line in the file where your search term is. The developer told me to look for tips on how to achieve this with EmEditor @ https://docs.xbench.net/user-guide/xbench-settings/

There, it is explained how to achieve this with Textpad and Notepad++.

See:

> For example, to configure TextPad 4 for line positioning, you must
> select there the **Textpad** executable and specify the following in
> Command-Line Parameters: **$filename($line,$column)**. Similarly, to
> configure **Notepad++**, you must select its executable and specify the
> following in Command-Line Parameters: **$filename -n$line**. Other text
> editors will require different values for this field. **Please check
> your text editor’s documentation for the suitable values.**

I had a look at EmEditors command line options @ http://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_file_file_commandline.html, but can't figure out how to do this. Can someone help me?

Michael Beijer (technical/patent translator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

`$filename /l $line /cl $column`

If a file name contains a space, you might need to use this:

`"$filename" /l $line /cl $column`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Yutaka! The first one works perfectly. I haven't needed to use the second one (but will try if necessary).

I'll also notify the people at Xbench and hopefully they will add this to their help documentation for future Xbench users using EmEditor!

Michael